# Include bootstrap in my HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this VERY simple line of code. I am just starting in doing some Javascript coding but I cannot make this work. Can you please tell me why?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>My Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is an example of a paragraph.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger daw!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The bootstrap is not appearing on the page.

Comment: your forget to include bootstrap.css

Comment: you need the css for it.

Comment: where should i put it?

Comment: in `<head></head>` section  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">`

Comment: got it! thanks! I just need to add the css file. LOL. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootsrap has Javascript, CSS and an optional theme. From the [Getting Started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) link on the bootstrap site you have the following code which will include them all for you.
If you are hosting the files yourself, just update the paths to the files.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: +1 for the optional line of code. Using the CDN will make your project load faster, Please note: if you don't have control about the files it's always a good thing to keep a backup copy of any file you use in your project, even if you'll never in need of the backup files , for example "What would you do if they take down the version you use?" You would be happy if you still have a copy of the file(s).....

Answer (score 0):

Add this between your `head` tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include css file path, here i used `BootstrapCDN`. And try to learn about bootstrap from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/) . I hope this is helpful.

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>My Website</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <p>This is an example of a paragraph.</p>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger daw!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed including **CSS**.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap requires jquery as a dependency.

Use the following code as suggested by rdn87

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Bootstrap</h1>
  <p>Text goes here</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can also choose to move scripts to footer or defer them for faster page load.